# Generate result report testing with Nunit and SpecFlow using .NET core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, nunit, specflow

I have a project ASP.NET core 3.1 which I integrate unit test with NUnit, Everything work fine but I want to genrate xml report test to generate html report.

I am using:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="nunit" Version="3.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.15.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow" Version="3.1.97" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic" Version="1.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.NUnit" Version="3.1.97" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation" Version="3.1.97" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I tried to generate with dotnet test with below command:

```
 dotnet test C:\Users\Ankitr\source\repos\API_BDDFramework\API_BDDFramework\API_BDDFramework.csproj --test-adapter-path C:\Users\Ankitr\source\repos\API_BDDFramework\API_BDDFramework\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\NUnit3.TestAdapter.dll --results-directory C:\Report
```

But I am getting an error and I am sure the path is correct:
`'C:\Users\Ankitr\source\repos\API_BDDFramework\API_BDDFramework\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\NUnit3.TestAdapter.dll' specified in the 'TestAdapterPath' is invalid. Error: The custom test adapter search path provided was not found, provide a valid path and try again.`

Anyone please help me here to generate test report with Nunit and Specflow using .NetCore

Comment: [`dotnet test`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test) accepts path to test project dll. Adapter must be passed with separate argument `-a`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Thank you for your quick response. Tried with this way as well. But did not worked.

Comment: The `test-adapter-path` requires a directory and not a file path. Try with  `dotnet test C:\Users\Ankitr\source\repos\API_BDDFramework\API_BDDFramework\API_BDDFramework.csproj --test-adapter-path C:\Users\Ankitr\source\repos\API_BDDFramework\API_BDDFramework\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ --results-directory C:\Report`